# Is is possible to create a "send-message-to(..)" URL for Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

With mail you can create an URL like `mailto:john.doe@example.com?subject=The%20message`. If you click that link, an e-mail message editor will be opened with the provided emailaddress and subject.

With WhatsApp you can do the same: `https://wa.me/1234567890?text=The%20message`.

It it also possible to do this with Google Hangouts, so it opens a chat with a provided emailaddress? When I check de [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference) I only see REST documentation for bots and such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on this case: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58767/create-direct-link-to-google-hangouts-chat

The final URL is:

`https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/1XXXXXXXXXXXX`

As you can see, you need an **ID** of the person, `1XXXXXXXXXXXX` and it is not `person@gmail.com` format.

If you want you can **file a Feature Request** following the next link, **requesting alternative format(email)** for an ID:
`https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en`

I hope this solves your doubts.